# how to filter data from store in extJS?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Please see bellow code, that I use for filtering data.

```
listeners: {
    keyup: function (e, t, eOpts) {
        var text = e.getValue();
        var s = Ext.getStore('TempSensorDetailsStore');
        s.clearFilter();
        if (text) {
            s.filterBy(function (rec) {
                var str = (rec.get('vehicleNo')).toLowerCase();
                var res = str.indexOf(text.toLowerCase());

                if (res == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            s.clearFilter();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code get filter the data, But not as per my expectations,

Search Result showing record which is matching the first letter of *vehicle Number* only...it should return the *vehicle No* if that character is present in *Vehicle no*

**For Example.**
Vehicle No.Abc-37046 and if user search 37046 then also it returns vehicle

Comment: The given example is your requirement or current behavior?

Comment: `indexOf` gives you the first index (else -1) that the string appears. You're explicitly checking the first index is at the start of the string.

Comment: So what I have to do changes in my Code?

Comment: @ankit chaudhary, Example is current behavior.

Comment: if Vehicle No.Abc-37046 and if user search 37046 then also I want to returns vehicle, But above code not behave like given example

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Solution,

There was just need to change code

```
 if (res >- 1)
```

Instead of

```
 if (res == 0)
```